# Knockout updating observableArray created with mapping extension

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model that looks like this:

```js
im.co.userPayments.UserPaymentViewModel = function(data) {
 var self = this;
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

The data that comes from the server is an object that has a list of PaymentData objects. When the page first loads everything is fine. All bindings to PaymentData on the page look and function correctly. The problem I have is updating the PaymentData observable array after getting new data from the server.

The user has the ability to select a different option on the page and via an ajax call get a new list of PaymentData objects from the server.

After the ajax call returns I try to update the observable array by doing the following:

```js
viewModel.PaymentData(newData);
```

This code produces errors in a custom binding that is used on the page. Here is the code for the custom binding:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.paymentAmount = {
 init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  $(element).blur(function() {
   // Get the value stored in the input box.
   var elementVal = $(element).val();
   var val = valueAccessor();

   // Update the underlying view model value.
   val(elementVal);
  });
 },
 update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  var displayVal;

  var context = bindingContext.$data;

  if (val < 0) {
   // By rule, if the amount is less than zero it will
   // be set to zero.
   // Update the value of Total
   context.Amount(0);
   displayVal = "0.00";

   // Set color to red to indicate to the user that the
   // payment value was changed from a negative amount
   // to zero.
   $(element).css('color', 'red');
  } else {
   $(element).css('color', ''); // set to default color.
   displayVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  }

  $(element).val(displayVal);
 }
}
```

Like I stated earlier, when initially loading the page from the server everything works correctly including the code in the custom binding. However, when attempting to refresh the data with a new list after an ajax call I get error. The error occurs on this line in the custom binding:

```js
context.Amount(0);
```

I don't have the exact error text but it is something about not being a valid function.

I don't understand what is happening here. Any insight provided will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the instance of ObservableArray in the code you submitted?

Comment: It's created by the mapping extension and is called PaymentData

Comment: A JSFiddle or something similar would be helpful

Comment: I'll try to come up with a fiddle, but I don't know if I could boil this down something like that.